# Display page counter in pdf with css

Tags: css, pdf, google-chrome-headless

i'm using chrome headless to geneate a pdf and i want to show the total page number but nothing will be displayed with the following code :

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0.5cm;
  padding: 0 1.5cm;

  counter-increment: page;
  counter-reset: page 1;
}
span.page-counter {
  content: counter(page);
}
```

And in the html :

```
<h2 class="heading">
  (1/<span class="page-counter"></span>)
</h2>
```

I call chrome headless with the following parameters :
--headless --disabled-gpu --no-margins --print-to-pdf-no-header --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security'

The content of span 'page-counter' is empty with this code.
Thank's in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to make sure you are setting `displayHeaderFooter` to true and that you provide the `footerTemplate`. The class you should use is either `.pageNumber` or `.totalPages` depending on which value you want to display.

Comment: I understand your answer @DanMullin but in my case, i use the command line. After reading the doc, i think that displayHeaderFooter and footerTemplate options cannot be set by command line. Maybe, i'm wrong ?